# Provide a grammar to generate strings that are only made of 1’s, where A={0,1}

Tags: computer-science, formal-grammar

My solution so far is as follow:

S -> 1S | 1

Is it necessary to include lambda in this grammar?

Edit:

To further elaborate, my logic is that since lambda is not 1 it does not belong in the grammar and my solution as is, is sufficient enough to properly generate strings of only 1. such as 1,11,111,1111....

Is this logic flawed or is it correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, there’s no 0 in $\Lambda$.

Comment: okay I have tried my best to iterate on my question, im basically asking if I should use lambda instead of 1 in the grammar

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "strings that are only made of 1's",
one could argue that the empty string $\lambda$ is only made of 1's, since every character in it is 1 (basically, universal quantification on an empty set is trivially true).

Therefore, I would say that both languages:
$$
L_1 = \{\lambda, 1, 11, 111, \dots\}
$$
and
$$
L_2 = \{1, 11, 111, \dots\}
$$
are correct interpretations of "strings that are only made of 1's",
therefore it truly depends on whether you want $L_1$ or $L_2$. If anything, I would pick $L_1$ as to avoid ambiguity I would usually explicitly state that I am interested in non-empty strings if i wanted to denote the language $L_2$.

Hope this helps!